# Using auth and role middleware together

Tags: laravel, authentication, permissions, roles

so I'm trying to redirect users according to the role of them to their dashboards. But when I login the page redirects back to the login page, and not the link it is supposed to go to. When I remove the auth middleware the page redirects but I get a 403 :user not logged in error. This is my code :

AuthContoller.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Login;
use App\Models\Signup;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $role = $request->input('role');

        $guard = $this->getGuardByRole($role);

        if (!$guard) {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Invalid role');
        }

        Auth::shouldUse($guard);

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication successful
            switch ($role) {
                case 'super admin':
                case 'admin':
                case 'additional admin':
                    // $role = auth()->user()->role;
                    return redirect()->route('admin');
                    break;
    
                case 'user':
                    // $role = auth()->user()->role;
                    return redirect()->route('user');
                    break;
            }
        }
// return view($viewName, ['userRole' => $userRole]);
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Invalid login credentials');
    }

    protected function getGuardByRole($role)
    {
        switch ($role) {
            case 'user':
                return 'web';
            case 'super admin':
            case 'additional admin':
                return 'sadmin';
            case 'admin':
                return 'admin';
            default:
                // Handle default or unknown role
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

web.php :

```
Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('commons.login');
});

Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
Route::middleware(['role:super admin|admin|additional admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/home', function () {
        return view('admin.home');
    })->name('admin');
   
});
Route::middleware(['role:user'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/home', function () {
        return view('user.home');
    })->name('user');
    
});
});
```

config/auth.php :

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Signup::class,
        ],
        'sadmins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Login::class,
        ],
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins', // Use a custom 'admins' provider for the 'admin' guard
        ],
        'sadmin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'sadmins', // Use a custom 'admins' provider for the 'admin' guard
        ],
    ],
```

kernel.php :

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
        'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
        'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
    ];


 protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Please help

I tried using view in the Authcontroller instead of redirect() function if i do that the pages load properly but on the login page itself it doesn't load of the admin/home or user/home page

error update : The page admin/home or user/home gets loaded in the developer tools network tab but with a 302 found status, any ideas ?

Comment: why are you using different guards? Does signup and login models have email and password columns?

Comment: Hi, yes they have email and password columns, I am passing the input variables and checking them in 3 tables. The table the credentials match determine the role of the user

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role']], function() { *routes here* })
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.